# Draw childnode on click of a node in forcelayout d3js

Tags: d3.js, svg, force-layout

I want to add childnodes on click of a node in forcelayout pattern d3js application, here is my jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ram140488/712LLv76/4/). Here is childData for childnodes

```
var childData = [
                {   
                    "name": "x",
                     "size": 1983
                }, {
                    "name": "y",
                      "size": 2047
                }, {
                    "name": "z",
                     "size": 1375
                }, {
                    "name": "t",
                     "size": 1375
                }]
```

in the example. I did something like this in tree layput pattern but for forcelayout pattern i am facing issue to plot the nodes. Please help me out.

Comment: how is node like name x/y/z/t related to a particular node. can you please explain this in teh question

Comment: x/y/z/t is data of child node, which we will fetched on click any node using ajax call.

Comment: On click of a node, say we get 4 nodes which is x/y/z/t. We have to link these 4 nodes with the clicked node(parent node).

Comment: @Cyril still i am not able to resolve this. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry Bro! i am not able to fix this but i think this is very close to what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857054/collapsible-d3-force-directed-graph-with-non-tree-data please check this out.

Comment: Thanks Cyril for the link, it is helpful. Will try this.